# Find Mean with considering Date (including absence) in time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a Data frame it contains customer balance day-wise. Sample data looks like this:

```
Pstng Date  DailyCustomerBalance
2017-01-01  0
2017-01-09  78384.19
2017-01-13  600400.51
2017-01-18  749905.52
2017-01-20  152352.19
2017-02-16  154785.3
2017-02-17  365895.28
2017-02-20  284384.77
2017-02-28  284384.77
2017-03-06  829957.21
2017-03-07  1470165.4
2017-03-08  1534915.04
2017-03-20  1321371.95
2017-03-22  1525026.15
2017-04-13  1619142.93
2017-04-14  1947051.04
2017-04-19  2079602.99
2017-04-20  1330376.35
```

In this data frame i want to find average of DailyCustomerBalance. Now I can't simply use 
`df['DailyCustomerBalance'].mean() #o/p 907116.755`

It gives me wrong answer because absence of few dates. I need to consider absence date as previous date value (similar to `ffill`).

So far I have tried this following script:

```
df['Pstng Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Pstng Date'])
df['temp']=df['Pstng Date'].shift(-1)
df['maintained_days']=((df['temp'].sub(df['Pstng Date']))/np.timedelta64(1,'D')).fillna(1)
df['DailyCustomerBalanceWeightedWithDate']=(df['DailyCustomerBalance']*df['maintained_days'])

print (df['DailyCustomerBalanceWeightedWithDate'].sum())/(((df['Pstng Date'].max()-df['Pstng Date'].min())/np.timedelta64(1,'D'))+1)
```

`output:
780359.246909 #ok`

My above code works fine. But I have used too many operations for this problem.

Is there any other better way to solve this?
or any other mathematical approach simplify this issue?.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make sure your dates are in the index.  Use `pd.DataFrame.asfreq` and `pd.DataFrame.mean`

```
df.set_index('Pstng Date').asfreq('D').ffill().mean()

DailyCustomerBalance    780359.246909
dtype: float64
```